# Inserting and Joining tables at the same time

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to insert some values to the database via a form, but for that to happen tables must be joined, and the way that I have done it is not not working for me.... As it relates to the security issues in the code, that will be dealt with after, but for now I would be extremely grateful for some help...the data is not being stored in the database, after values are entered inside the form and the save button is clicked the form just empties itself

```
<?php
session_start();
include('php/connectdb.php');

if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['middlename']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['home_num']) && isset($_POST['cell_num']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['trn']) && isset($_POST['hiredate']) && isset($_POST['status']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['shift']) && isset($_POST['rank']) && isset($_POST['dob']) && isset($_POST['maritalstatus']) && isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['height']) && isset($_POST['weight']) && isset($_POST['helmet_size']) && isset($_POST['coat_size']) && isset( $_POST['pant_size']) && isset($_POST['boot_size']) && isset($_POST['glove_size']))
{
    $firstname = ucfirst($_POST['firstname']);
    $middlename = ucfirst($_POST['middlename']);
    $lastname = ucfirst($_POST['lastname']);
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $home_num = $_POST['home_num'];
    $cell_num = $_POST['cell_num'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $trn = $_POST['trn'];
    $hiredate = $_POST['hiredate'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $shift = $_POST['shift'];
    $rank = $_POST['rank'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $maritalstatus = $_POST['maritalstatus'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $kinname = ucfirst($_POST['kinname']);
    $kinnumber = $_POST['kinnumber'];
    $helmet_size = $_POST['helmet_size'];
    $coat_size = $_POST['coat_size'];
    $pant_size = $_POST['pant_size'];
    $boot_size = $_POST['boot_size'];
    $glove_size = $_POST['glove_size'];
    $transfer = $_POST['transfer'];

    $transferTo = $_POST['transferTo'];
    $dateTransferredTo = $_POST['dateTransferredTo'];
    $transferFrom = $_POST['transferFrom'];
    $dateTransferredFrom = $_POST['dateTransferredFrom'];
    $rankTransferredWith = $_POST['rankTransferredWith'];


    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($middlename) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($address) && !empty($home_num) && !empty($cell_num) && !empty($email) && !empty($trn) && !empty($hiredate) && !empty($status) && !empty($location) && !empty($shift) && !empty($rank) && !empty($dob) && !empty($maritalstatus) && !empty($gender) && !empty($height) && !empty($weight) && !empty($helmet_size) && !empty($coat_size) && !empty($boot_size) && !empty($glove_size) && !empty($transfer))
    {
        if($transfer == 'Yes'){
            $transfer = 1;
    }
    else{
        $transfer = 0;
    }

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO firefighterinfo(`firefighterinfo`.`firstName`, `firefighterinfo`.`middleName`, `firefighterinfo`.`lastName`, `firefighterinfo`.`address`, `firefighterinfo`.`telephone1`, `firefighterinfo`.`telephone2`, `firefighterinfo`.`emailAddress`, `firefighterinfo`.`taxRegistrationNo`, `firefighterinfo`.`hireDate`, `firefighterinfo`.`status`, `stationlocation`.`exactlocation`, `firefighterinfo`.`workShift`, `rank`.`rank`, `firefighterinfo`.`dateOfBirth`, `firefighterinfo`.`maritalStatus`, `firefighterinfo`.`gender`, `firefighterinfo`.`height`, `firefighterinfo`.`weight`, `firefighterinfo`.`kinName`, `firefighterinfo`.`kinContactNo`, `firefighterinfo`.`helmetSize`, `firefighterinfo`.`coatSize`, `firefighterinfo`.`pantSize`, `firefighterinfo`.`bootSize`, `firefighterinfo`.`gloveSize`, `firefighterinfo`.`transfer`)                     VALUES('$firstname', '$middlename', '$lastname', '$address', '$home_num', '$cell_num', '$email', '$trn', '$hiredate', '$status', '$location', '$shift', '$rank', '$dob', '$maritalstatus', '$gender', '$height', '$weight', '$kinname', '$kinnumber', '$helmet_size', '$coat_size', '$pant_size', '$boot_size', '$glove_size', '$transfer')
                SELECT `firefighterinfo`.fighterID`, `stationlocation`.`exactlocation`, `rank`.`rank` 
                FROM `firefighterinfo`
                INNER JOIN `stationlocation` ON `firefighterinfo`.`StationLocation_locationID` = `stationlocation`.locationID
                INNER JOIN `rank` ON `firefighterinfo`.`Rank_rankID` = `rank`.`rankID`";

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO transfer(`transferToStation`,`transferToDate`,`transferFromStation`,`transferFromDate`,`rankTranferredWith`) VALUES('$transferTo', '$dateTransferredTo', '$transferFrom', '$dateTransferredFrom', '$rankTransferredWith')";

    $query3 = "INSERT INTO user(`username`, `password`) VALUES ('$username','$password')";

    if($_POST['kinname'] == '' || $_POST['kinnumber']== ''){
        $_POST['kinname'] = null;
        $_POST['kinnumber'] = null;
    }

    $result = false;
    if(mysql_query('BEGIN')){
        if(mysql_query($query1) && mysql_query($query2) && mysql_query($query3))
        {
            $result = mysql_query('COMMIT');
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Insert Successful!");
              </script>';
        }
        else
        {
            mysql_query('ROLLBACK');
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Insert Unsuccessful!");
              </script>';
        }
    }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). And **please** stop storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: So what exactly isn't "working for you"? What happens?

Comment: the security issues in the code will be addressed after. The data is not being stored in the database. When the save button is clicked the form just empties itself and nothing happens afterwards.